# Symlink bash autocomplete

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

If I typer unrar-nonfree and double tap tab, I get the usual autocomplete result:

```
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~$ unrar-free /
backup.sh         initrd.img.old    mxx.lock          tmp/
bin/              killftp.sh        nohup.out         usr/
boot/             lastbackup.txt    proc/             var/
cdrom/            lib/              root/             vmlinuz
dev/              lost+found/       sbin/             vmlinuz.old
etc/              media/            selinux/
home/             mnt/              srv/
initrd.img        mxreport.sh.save  sys/
```

However if i type unrar (the symlink of unrar-nonfree created by update-alternatives)then double tap tab, I get the options instead:

```
michaelxu@michaelxu-server:~$ unrar
e   l   lb  lt  p   t   v   vb  vt  x
```

Does this have to do with symlinks? Is this a bug or a featrue?

Comment: Ooops i jsut realized this was a bad question

Comment: I don't think it's such a bad question. Why don't you just post an answer yourself? I assume you had to include `unrar-free` into the `unrar` completion function -- that could be a good info for somebody else.

Comment: Actually it wasnt a bad question :D, I still haven't solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with

`set mark-symlinked-directories on`

in *~/.inputrc* 
Solution is from http://www.pedrodiaz.com/cs/linux/bashtips.php

Comment: No more double tab:

`set show-all-if-ambiguous on` is also handy

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bash-completions`, just edit the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/unrar`. Close to the end of the file there is a line

```
complete -F _unrar unrar
```

Just *add* another one like that

```
complete -F _unrar unrar-free
```

Don't forget to open up a new terminal, so that the filechange gets read in.

Comment: You should contact the maintainers of bash-completion, so this is included by default -- if `unrar-free` is a common tool they probably will do it.